# Tuned way to grab HTML from URL

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, web-crawler

There are lot of questions and answers showing how to get HTML content from a URL, but I need a really fast algorithm because we have lots of Web connection's to make.

So which is the most efficient way to grab content (usually HTML) from URLs?

Comment: Im really disappointed from programmers here which are just Replicating the Question ,like Jethro here ,because Jethro ,here below is a programmer who Answered the question and guess what he's right and you're not ,you cant just tell me what's the Issue ,if you want to get points or a better job you need to think how to Solve a Problem not to tell others what's the problem kej!

Comment: some programmers here like to solve problems on their own and are just looking for suggestions, a little push in the right direction so to speak. Of all the questions on the web that you found about getting HTML content from URL, how many did you try? What made that solution slow that you wanted to try and find a faster one? It looks to me as if you wanted someone to do all the work for you, hence the down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) probably has a more simple api but both should work.

As far as running a lot of requests you should implement it using multiple threads or a thread pool. If the urls are on the same server you should be careful not to overload it.

If you want examples to implement it via a thread pool I can provide them.

Update

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WebClientApp
{
class MainClassApp
{
    private static int requests = 0;
    private static object requests_lock = new object();

    public static void Main() {

        List<string> urls = new List<string> { "http://www.google.com", "http://www.slashdot.org"};
        foreach(var url in urls) {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(GetUrl, url);
        }

        int cur_req = 0;

        while(cur_req<urls.Count) {

            lock(requests_lock) {
                cur_req = requests; 
            }

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }

private static void GetUrl(Object the_url) {

        string url = (string)the_url;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Stream data = client.OpenRead (url);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
        string html = reader.ReadToEnd ();

        /// Do something with html
        Console.WriteLine(html);

        lock(requests_lock) {
            requests++; 
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please provide me some Examples using thread Pool .

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are processing a very large number of urls (probably in the thousands) the above method will not work well and you will need some sort of batching (maybe 1000 at a time)

Comment: if there would be a way to Up Vote 10000 times i would do ,because it's working like a charm man and also using with Large number of URL's i`m increasing the timeout and it's working like a charm many thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Parallel.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783942.aspx) to set up all the requests and give it a generous [`MaxDegreesOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx).

You'll be spending most of your time waiting on I/O, so make as much use of multi-threading as possible.